# Post request looks like 2 different requests on ESP8266. Is this a Chrome bug?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, arduino, esp8266

I am setting up a server on ESP8266 WiFi module. Basic operation is, you request a URL. ESP serves that page. It has a form. You fill it in and click submit, and the browser sends POST request by AJAX. I am not using jQuery, just js. From Chrome dev-tools, it looks like all is well.

But on the ESP Server side, I noticed I am missing post data once in a while. After digging deep, I found this issue.

Ideal result from Chrome on my windows: And this works correctly. Post data comes in as expected.

```
+IPD,0,507:POST /wifi.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 63
Origin: http://192.168.4.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://192.168.4.1/wifi.htm
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0

ethOrWiFi=1&ewln=1&dhcp=1&ssid=Esensors&key=tgfgfdgfdtrd&auth=4
```

But on my Mac Chrome, I see the following result.

```
+IPD,0,472:POST /wifi.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 63
Origin: http://192.168.4.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://192.168.4.1/wifi.htm
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ml;q=0.6
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0

+IPD,0,63:ethOrWiFi=1&ewln=1&dhcp=1&ssid=Esensors&key=asdfasdfasdf&auth=4
```

And I can repeat this. The only different in each case is I am using Chrome on Windows as opposed to Chrome on Mac. To double check, I downloaded `Chrome canary version` and tried. The first request worked fine. From second request onwards, it shows this problem. Why is this happening? Any ideas? May be my laptop has issues? :)

Here are Chrome dev-tools info from Chrome on Mac (the one with the problem)

```
**Request Headers:**
POST /wifi.htm HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 61
Origin: http://192.168.4.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://192.168.4.1/wifi.htm
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ml;q=0.6
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH: AlexaToolbar/alx-4.0
**Request Payload**
ethOrWiFi=1&ewln=1&dhcp=1&ssid=Esensors&key=asdfasdfoi&auth=4
```

Comment: Did you try to capture communication by WireShark or tcpdump? My guess there is a flush after the headers and data were sent in another packet. But it's not a problem in the meaning of TCP. It's still one connection.

Comment: The only diff at the headers is do not track flag. I do not think that it would be a solution but maybe worth to test by disabling it from chrome settings.

Comment: And what is wrong with the second request? Are you talking about `+IPD,0,63:`?

Comment: @gre_gor The problem is, when the Server on ESP captures packets, it only takes the first set as the request and delivers it to the rest of the code. So when this happens, I miss the post data. I can do a work around on the server code, but I am not sure that I am understanding the real issue here. thats why I posted this queston

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Chrome on any OS. You should write your server so, it can handle the TCP stream even if you get the data in chunks.

Comment: @gre_gor ok thanks. I already have the work around server side code ready and running. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+IPD is the AT command that says data was received from the network.  `+IPD,0,63:` is saying to receive 63 bytes from connection 0.  That matches with your `Content-Length` header.  Notice that it also appears at the beginning of the header portion of the request.

Your WiFi library on the ESP side is throwing that in.  [Here](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_AT/blob/4d00060634d4c74267ad38d27aa58805680a872c/at/user/at_ipCmd.c#L274) and on line 281 is the source code where it might be happening.  There are a couple variables that affect whether or not the +IPD is added, maybe you have set or inadvertently changed one.

Comment: yes, I get it. what I dont understand is, why does it add +IPD for header, and another +IPD before post DATA when using some browser/ machine, and why few others make it come out as single stream (just one +IPD)

Comment: I think it's because the length of the message coming to the ESP is actually different. On the Mac request two separate packets were received.  If you measure the length of both strings, the PC version says 507 and it actually is 507 from start to end, but on the MAC it says 472 so two +IPDs were needed.  Maybe TCP settings.